# File upload error using AmazonS3

Tags: 7, files

I'm trying to use the AmazonS3 service to host videos from my Drupal site. I'm using:

Drupal 7.16

AmazonS3 7.x-1.0-beta7

AWS SDK for PHP 7.x-5.4

Libraries 7.x-2.0

Video 7.x-2.8+3-dev

I've also downloaded the AWS SDK Library 1.5.15 which I've put in my libraries folder.

I configured the amazon module to use the bucket I had set up on Amazon and put in the correct access keys for AWS SDK. I then set up my video field to use AmazonS3, however every time I try to upload a file I get the error:

> "The file could not be uploaded."

When I check the log files the error details are:

> "The upload directory s3:// for the file field field_video_s3 could
>   not be created or is not accessible. A newly uploaded file could not
>   be saved in this directory as a consequence, and the upload was
>   canceled."

I have also set `allow_url_fopen = On` in my php.ini file.

Can anyone tell me if I am missing something? I have not added any special permissions or additional users to the Amazon bucket, and am not sure what permissions I would need to add if I do.

I would be grateful for any suggestions.

Ben

Comment: Okay, finally after about a day and a bit of trial and error I managed to find the answer. It was because my bucket name had dots in it. I've now removed the dots and my files are uploading fine. I found the answer in the issue [Error with bucket names containing dots (.) over SSL](http://drupal.org/node/1673888).